# react send a request to server on constructor for set list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in react I want to send a sync instead of async ajax request to the server for getting category list on constructor because if the server is busy, the response will be late that means the page will be rendered without category list.

I think it is a good idea that creates/edit a JSON file after every category event but I want to learn the right way.

how can I do it or what is the right way to it?

Comment: Why does it matter if category list is empty on the first render? If you make your API call with you `componentDidMount()` and set state as the response, your component will re-render with the content. Unless you require server side rendering?

Comment: i doesn't matter. ajax request is async and if the server is slow or busy, component will be rendered without category list ? i don't want it

Comment: Yes but you can at least display a loading icon of some sort then. If you are waiting for the ajax request to finish before rendering anything, the user has less idea what is happening. You essentially want the whole app to stop loading just because you are waiting for the ajax request to finish.

Comment: ok i got it and will try ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would set an empty array in the state in the constructor. And in componentDidMount I would start an async request. When it returns it updates the state and you get your category list.
You can set a loading state as well. Set true at the start of ajax request and set false as you get back the result.
Use the loading state with conditional rendering to display a loading indicator.

Comment: i assume that the server is slow or busy ... async response not come back on time ...